# File access with C++ on WindowsPhone 8.1 Silverlight

Tags: file, silverlight, dll, windows-phone-8.1

My project use to be a WP8.1 WRT project -> C++ + Xmal,

Now I convert it into a WP8.1 Silverlight project - C# + Xmal + C++DLL.

Because I must use Silverlight and C++(openssl) at the same time.

This is how I access the file in the WP8.1 WRT project

For file in assets:

```
wchar_t pw_filedir[MAX_PATH];

wcscpy_s( pw_filedir, MAX_PATH, Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation->Path->Data() );
wcscat_s( pw_filedir, MAX_PATH, L"\\Assets\\FileName" );
// Then I can do file access with C style
```

For file in Isolate storage

```
wchar_t pw_filedir[MAX_PATH];
wcscpy_s( pw_filedir, MAX_PATH, Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->Path->Data() );
wcscat_s( pw_filedir, MAX_PATH, L"\\FileName" );
// Then I can do file access with C style
```

Now both of them no longer works on WP8.1 Silverlight.

Did any of you try to access file on WindowsPhone silverlight?

Here I mean:

```
Project - WP8.1 SL (C#)
Dll - WP8.1 SL native Dll (C++)
```

So I need to do a C++ file access in a native DLL in a WP8.1 SL C# project..

I'll appreciate a lot for the answers!

Comment: What do you mean by "no longer works"? The Win32 file APIs work fine in SL 8.1 apps and those paths should be valid. Do you have specific error codes you get back from the file APIs?

Comment: But the problem is, they are not. I don't know why. It work properly in WP8.1 WRT, but didn't in  WP8.1 SL.
Just failed at fopen().

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't try `fopen` (`CreateFile2` works just fine though). Do you have a more complete code sample you can post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solve it.

It's funny,

I put a file in the assets folder,

Let's say the name of the file is Blah.yyy

It works well on WP8.1 WRT project,

But it didn't work properly on WP8.1 SL project.

But after I rename it to Blah.png,

The C style file function could detect it.

So, I guess the file itself was not packed into the package.

It has a pack filter, I still don't know where to set it. :-P

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Silverlight on Windows Phone 8.1 you have to use the namespace [System.IO.IsolatedStorage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.IsolatedStorage(v=vs.110).aspx) to read from and to write to files. A small example:

```
private static void StoreToISF(String key, String value)
{
    using (var mutex = new Mutex(true, "mutex"))
    {
        if (mutex.WaitOne(250))
        {
            var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            if (isf.FileExists(key + ".txt"))
                isf.DeleteFile(key + ".txt");
            var stream = isf.OpenFile(key + ".txt", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
            var bytes = new byte[value.Length * sizeof(char)];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(value.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            stream.Close();
        }

        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer,
My project is a Silverlight project,
But it use a C++ dll, in the native dll, it need to do a file access operation,
So the file access should be in C++ at dll layer. :-P

Actually it's OpenSSL, it needs to read a file. -_-b
It works on WP8.1 WRT